# Scraping website in Python

Tags: python, html

I have a problem with website scrape in Python. Specifically, the problem is I can not scrape live scores websites with library BeautifulSoup in Python. The problem in my code is that: the html elements can not be inserted into list in Python.

```
import urllib3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import pymysql

import timeit

data_list=[]

url_p=requests.get('my url website')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url_p.text,'html.parser')

vathmoi_table=soup.find("td",class_="label")

for table in soup.findAll("table"):

    print(table)


print(vathmoi_table)

for team_name in soup.findAll("td"):

    data_list_r=[]  

    simvolo = team_name.find("img")
    name=team_name.find("td",class_="label")
    vathmologia=team_name.find("td",class_="points")

    if(name!=None):
        data_list_r.append(symvolo.get_text().strip())
        data_list_r.append(name.get_text().strip())
        data_list_r.append(vathmologia.get_text().strip())

    data_list.append(data_list_r)

    for tr_parse in team_name.findAll("tr"):
        team=tr_parse.find("td",class_="team")

        if(team!=None):
            print(team.get_text())


print(data_list)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the html elements can not be inserted into list"? Where is the error? What is the output of your code?

Comment: When parse html code from URL then i insert into list in python and the output of list is "None".